# Passing array to the view in flask

Tags: python, flask

i'm beginner with python and flask.I wanted to pass a list to the view file from .py file and did this:

python file:

```
 @app.route('/admin',methods=['GET'])

 def panelSettings():   
     myList = ["gan","dalf"]
     return render_template('admin.html',list=myList)
```

html file:

```
my list's first eleman is:{{ list[0] }}
```

however this code doesn't work.It says:

```
 myList is not defined
```

My purpose was pass multiple or more variable to the view.What should i do?

My Traceback is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ozcan/flask/flask/app.py", line 1823, in __call__
   return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "/Users/ozcan/flask/flask/app.py", line 1811, in wsgi_app
  response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
File "/Users/ozcan/flask/flask/app.py", line 1809, in wsgi_app
  response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "/Users/ozcan/flask/flask/app.py", line 1482, in full_dispatch_request
  rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "/Users/ozcan/flask/flask/app.py", line 1480, in full_dispatch_request
  rv  = self.dispatch_request()
File "/Users/ozcan/flask/flask/app.py", line 1466, in dispatch_request
  return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "/Users/ozcan/Documents/python/app.py", line 104, in panel
  return render_template("panel.html",route=route)
File "/Users/ozcan/flask/flask/templating.py", line 127, in render_template
  context, ctx.app)
File "/Users/ozcan/flask/flask/templating.py", line 109, in _render
  rv = template.render(context)
File "/Users/ozcan/flask/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Jinja2-2.6-  py2.7.egg/jinja2/environment.py", line 894, in render
  return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
File "/Users/ozcan/Documents/python/templates/panel.html", line 1, in top-level template code
  {% extends "layout.html" %}
File "/Users/ozcan/Documents/python/templates/layout.html", line 62, in top-level template code
  {%block panel%}{%endblock%}
File "/Users/ozcan/Documents/python/templates/panel.html", line 11, in block "panel"
  {{ list[0]}}
File "/Users/ozcan/flask/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Jinja2-2.6-py2.7.egg/jinja2/environment.py", line 353, in getitem
  return obj[argument]
UndefinedError: 'list' is undefined
```

Comment: Can you show the full traceback?

Comment: Could you include the full traceback of that error in your post?

Comment: Here is my error http://oi47.tinypic.com/2rg0r45.jpg

Comment: Instead of an image, please copy the traceback (the error page has instructions on how to get the traceback, click on the "traceback" heading) and paste it into your question.

Comment: i've edited,sorry about that

Comment: Your traceback says `list`, but your quoted error says "myList" - can you double-check both the stack trace *and* your controller (the function under `@app.route` and make sure that both are accurate?

Comment: Try using the flask.g instead of your way.

Comment: `list` is a built-in function. I'd advise against using the name for something else.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use `list` as the name of your variable because `list` is a reserved keyword in Python.

Comment: This definitely seems like the most likely problem IMO